# Registering JavaScript/CSS in a Custom Control for a New Umbraco Data Type

Tags: c#, asp.net, umbraco

I'm working on a custom data type for Umbraco based on Tim's Blog Post: http://www.nibble.be/?p=90

I've got it *mostly* working, but I need to include a colorbox (http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/) for one of my displays.  This requires jQuery, jQuery's colorbox, and a colorbox.css with a bunch of images.  Since it's a custom control, I can't just drop the items in a directory and link to them.  My control is called DoctypeSelector and here is the code as it is now:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI;

[assembly: System.Web.UI.WebResource("DocTypeSelector.Styles.colorbox.css", "text/css")]
[assembly: System.Web.UI.WebResource("DocTypeSelector.Scripts.jquery.colorbox-min.js", "text/js")]
[assembly: System.Web.UI.WebResource("DocTypeSelector.Control.DoctypeSelector.js", "text/js")]
namespace DocTypeSelector
{
    public class DoctypeSelectorControl : Panel
    {
        private HyperLink lnkSelector;

    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);

        if (lnkSelector == null)
                {
                    lnkSelector = new HyperLink();
        }

        lnkSelector.Text = "Select...";
        lnkSelector.NavigateUrl = "#";
        lnkSelector.CssClass = "selectTool";

        System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlLink cssLink = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlLink();
        cssLink.Href = cssLink.Href = Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(this.GetType(),"DocTypeSelector.Styles.colorbox.css");

            cssLink.Attributes.Add("rel", "stylesheet");

            cssLink.Attributes.Add("type", "text/css");

            this.Page.Header.Controls.Add(cssLink);

                 this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div style=\"display: none\"><div id=\"selectBox\">Welcome!</div></div>"));



            this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude(

                "DocTypeSelector.DoctypeSelector.js",

                this.Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(typeof(DoctypeSelectorControl), "DocTypeSelector.Control.DoctypeSelector.js"));



            this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude(

                "DocTypeSelector.jquery.colorbox-min.js",

                this.Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(typeof(DoctypeSelectorControl), "DocTypeSelector.Scripts.jquery.colorbox-min.js"));

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If anyone is interested, it was not an Umbraco issue I was running into but how to bind JS and CSS files inside an ASP.NET.  First, make sure all CSS and JS files are set to embedded resource.  Above your class declaration, make sure to include your files in the assembly:

```
[assembly: WebResource("Umbraco.Datatypes.DoctypeSelector.Styles.colorbox.css", "text/css", PerformSubstitution = true)]
[assembly: WebResource("Umbraco.Datatypes.DoctypeSelector.Scripts.jquery.colorbox-min.js", "text/javascript")]
[assembly: WebResource("Umbraco.Datatypes.DoctypeSelector.Control.DoctypeSelector.js", "text/javascript")]
[assembly: WebResource("Umbraco.Datatypes.DoctypeSelector.Styles.images.border.png", "image/png")]
[assembly: WebResource("Umbraco.Datatypes.DoctypeSelector.Styles.images.controls.png", "image/png")]
[assembly: WebResource("Umbraco.Datatypes.DoctypeSelector.Styles.images.loading.gif", "image/gif")]
[assembly: WebResource("Umbraco.Datatypes.DoctypeSelector.Styles.images.loading_background.png", "image/png")]
```

Make sure to declare each file type correctly (i.e. text/javascript, text/css, etc.).  The "PerformSubstitution = true" allows you to bind these items dynamically in the CSS itself.   For example, when I wanted to call controls.png in the CSS I used:

```
<%=WebResource("Umbraco.Datatypes.DoctypeSelector.Styles.images.controls.png")%>
```

Finally, you include the files in your OnInit:

```
// Register colorbox css
            string css = "<link href=\"" + Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(typeof(DoctypeSelectorControl),"Umbraco.Datatypes.DoctypeSelector.Styles.colorbox.css") + "\" type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" />";
            this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(DoctypeSelectorControl), "cssFile", css, false);

            // Register doctype javascript
            this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude(
                "Umbraco.Datatypes.DoctypeSelector.doctypeSelector.js",
                this.Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(typeof(DoctypeSelectorControl), "Umbraco.Datatypes.DoctypeSelector.Control.DoctypeSelector.js"));
```

I hope this helps someone else!